# Extra render time in Chrome Dev Tools Timeline Frames

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools

There are plenty of videos and tutorials out there geared towards reducing the compositing, layout, and paint times for a frame using Dev tools, but I'm not clear of what to do once those times are well below the allotted time, but the frame still takes far too long to render.

Any tips on determining what exactly is happening in a frame that causes it to render so slowly?

[image: chrome devtools timeline]

Comment: I should've investigated this more. Turns out that empty head space at the top of the frame is actually idle time before rendering the next frame. It's still bad, as it usually means that I have a frame where multiple recalculate styles are taking place, forcing the frame to take longer to render.

Answer (score 1):

Paul Irish and Paul Lewis touch this topic briefly [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0_jD8nO5Zw&feature=player_detailpage&t=2181). According to this video, white bar indicates browser waiting for a CPU or a GPU and there is nothing that developer can do to fix this (assuming that he is working on a 'standard' website with no canvas/webGL). However, IMO both Pauls don't sound very convincing when talking about this. I guess, it's just hard to explain briefly (and maybe 8 sips of beer that I've counted from the beginning of the video are to blame :) ).

Comment: It's a bit frustrating. There's been a huge narrative of "jank-busting" on the web lately, with almost all of the discussion focused on reducing scripting, rendering, and paint times via the dev tools timeline. I've put a lot of effort into getting these times well below the 60fps threshold, and many frames still seem to be lasting 30ms or above.

Comment: BTW, the point in the video that Konrad mentioned where they discuss the transparent frames is 36:20, and specifically the part that applies to my issue (transparent frames that blow way past even the 30fps threshold) is at 37:25.

Comment: There solution to this is: the cpu may be doing extra work that prevents it from rendering the frame in time, and that to rule this out you should close all other applications and web pages and run the page-in-question in an Incognito tab to ensure you're not getting interference from other pages, extensions, etc.