# Large "idle" bars in Chrome dev tools Frames Timeline

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, google-chrome-devtools, requestanimationframe

I'm drawing some shapes (arc, lineTo, etc.) to a  using `requestAnimationFrame`. Nothing too fancy, but I'm noticing some occasional jerky animation. I profiled using the Timeline inspector in Chrome dev tools, and am seeing a large amount of idle time per frame, some of which drops the FPS below 60 (see screenshot). Is there a known cause or resolution for this?

[image: frames with lots of idle time]

Comment: Similar questions: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302286/what-causes-chrome-timeline-frame-to-have-so-much-empty-white-space?rq=1),
[two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423330/web-inspector-profiling-with-frames-finding-the-cause-of-performance-problems),
[three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257206/extra-render-time-in-chrome-dev-tools-timeline-frames). No helpful info. A few references to [this G+ post by Nat Duca](https://plus.google.com/+NatDuca/posts/BvMgvdnBvaQ?e=-RedirectToSandbox), but I'm not doing anything with 3D transforms, so I don't think it's applicable.

Comment: From [DevTools documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline#frames_mode): "You may notice regions of a frame that are light-gray or clear (hollow). These regions indicate, respectively: 1.) Activity that was not instrumented by DevTools 2.) Idle time between display refresh cycles. The frames in the recording below show both un-instrumented activity and idle time." However, that doesn't really explain how to fix the problem. If the clear section of the frame is idle time, why does it cause frames to skip?

Comment: I have the same issue; frames finishing in like 3ms but with insane idle times, sometimes 200ms; what gives? broken dev tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drawing shapes to a canvas is apparently computationally expensive, and must fall under "activity that was not instrumented by DevTools." I solved my performance issue by first drawing shapes to an offscreen canvas cache, then using `drawImage` to copy back to the main canvas.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post what your timeline profile looks like after the improvements?

Comment: @sethro Seems the interface has changed a bit, but [here's a similar screenshot](http://imgur.com/0WQPg8b). Note the computation/rendering falls well within each ~16ms frame.

Answer (score 1):

Compare those peaks to the memory graph. In my experience, large idle spikes seem to coincide with garbage collection.